# Java compilation behavior

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

In the code below, why it does not compile without the last return statement.

```
private boolean fileExists(final File[] files, final String name) {
   if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
   for (final File file : files) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // why is this neessary?
}
```

Comment: simplified example could be `boolean syntaxCheck() { if (true) { return true; } return false;/* why is 'return false' necessary?*/ }`

Answer (score 3):

If `files` is empty you don't enter the loop but the function need to return a `boolean`. That's why

Answer (score 1):

Because what happens if `files` is empty?

You need the second return statement for that case.

Answer (score 1):

because `files` could have been empty. The method must return a boolean value in all cases as defined in the signature!

Answer (score 1):

If `files` is empty (the compiler doesn't know, after all) then nothing would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared that the method returns a boolean value

```
private boolean fileExists(final File[] files, final String name)
```

If you dont want it to return anything then declare the method as 'void'

```
private void fileExists(final File[] files, final String name)
```

You probably do need the 'return' because what happens if both 'if' statements are false?

Answer (score -3):

If the `return` inside `if` and `for` are not executed we still need to return a value. So a `return` statement is required.

Looking at the code we see that either the return in the `if` or the `for` will be hit, but this cannot be inferred by the compiler.